# Resources not being loaded when launch debug mode in VisualStudio project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am launching a VS project (ASP.Net and Angular) in debug mode, but none of the resources are being loaded.

[image]

**Index.cshtml**

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/inline.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/polyfills.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/vendor.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/main.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}

<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">@(ViewBag.Message ?? "SPORTS-STORE")</a>
</div>
<div class="p-1 bg-info">
    calling app.component.html:
    <app-root></app-root>
</div>
```

**scripts property from package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

the files exist at the path `~/dist/` in my project. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `dist` folder inside `wwwroot` folder. Normally, you need to run command `npm run build` which will create dist folder.

Comment: So I need to copy the dist folder manually into wwwroot every time I change the project?

Comment: In angular app you have `package.json` file. so can you share the `scripts` json property value in this file?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Added to the post, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Update "build": "ng build  --deploy-url /dist/" in package.json and then run command `npm run build` and it will create dist folder inside wwwroot folder